# Mismatched anonymous define() module: function(){"use strict";return axe}

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, browser-link

I have this odd error for some reason:

> "Mismatched anonymous define() module: function(){"use strict";return
>   axe} http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch"

After setting some JS breakpoints, I found the error source here:

```
a [browserlink] Line 363: 
    /*! aXe v2.0.5
 * Copyright (c) 2016 Deque Systems, Inc.
 * ...etc... */
...etc...&&define([],function(){"use strict";return axe}),...etc...
```

So, realizing it was in the dynamically generated "browserlink" code, I disabled "browserlink" in Visual Studio, and the problem went away (everything is perfect, no issues). It seems that `function(){"use strict";return axe}` is getting stuck in the requirejs queue? *('defQueue')* This happens when the web app is first launched, BUT there are no errors YET. The error occurs only later on, when I do something that uses requirejs. After some analysis, I found that this call in requirejs:

```
//Grab defines waiting in the global queue.
intakeDefines();
```

fails here:

```
while (defQueue.length) {
    args = defQueue.shift();
    if (args[0] === null) {
        return onError(makeError('mismatch', 'Mismatched anonymous define() module: ' + args[args.length - 1]));
```

where args == [null,[],"function(){"use strict";return axe}"]

The question is, can anyone help me figure out why this conflict may exist?  Is this a bug of some sort with VS browserlink?

Comment: Your first solution saved my life today. Thank you

Comment: Glad I could help ;)

Answer (score 12):

This seems to be related to `WebAccessibilityChecker` so try to disable the extension, then it should work again.

I already created an issue for that [here](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebAccessibilityChecker/issues/9).

Comment: I've been beating my head against my desk for hours trying to solve this. Your answer fixed my issue. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7):

I did mention this in the question, but for those looking for solutions, one work around is to also disable "browserlink" in visual studio for now.